# RSA API Erro 500

Tags: archer

I'm trying to make content inclusion via the RSA Archer API, though it is returning me error 500 and the following message

{
     "Message": "An error has occurred."
}

How do I debug and identify this error?

Answer (score 0):

With a 500 Error the first spot I'd check is making sure that the API is not a folder in IIS, and it's an application. Then check that it's using the same application pool as the parent (/RSAArcher or /Archer).

Without any further information on what call you're trying to make, or the code you're using to make that call, that's all I can suggest.